# Restart NodeJS server if remote MySQL server is down

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash, ubuntu

I have a few NodeJS servers hosted each one on its own VM machine (with Ubuntu Server), all connected to the same MySQL server, remotely, on a different VM machine.
From time to time MySQL server restarts or crashes and recovers (not sure since we don't have access to that one) and all NodeJS servers hang, awaiting for changes (I'm using nodemon to start them) and the only solution is to manually restart it (Ctrl + C / nodemon app.js)
I need a way to restart each NodeJS server in its own terminal window, as soon as MySQL server restarts/recovers.

I was thinking maybe I can create a script that runs in background (cronjob every 1 hour or something similar) that will restart the NodeJS server if MySQL is down, until the server doesn't hang anymore, if possible.

Or, kill NodeJS and the current terminal session altogether and open another terminal to the server's location and run "nodemon app.js".

Problem is, I'm not sure how to do this or even if this is the best approach.

I figure it out I can ping the MySQL server and check if the server is down or not but from there on I'm stuck.

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ping@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ping';

#!/bin/bash

MYSQL_USER=ping
MYSQL_PASS=ping
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
mysqladmin ping ${MYSQL_CONN} 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
MYSQLD_RUNNING=${?}
if [ ${MYSQLD_RUNNING} -eq 1 ]; then {SOMETHING_HERE_MAYBE} ; fi
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this or maybe some script example?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is [PM2 restart strategies](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/), I'm pretty sure PM2 have functionality to restart server in case of non-zero exit code `(Skip Auto Restart For Specific Exit Codes strategy)`, so what you can do is in the code where you are trying to connect to your DB in case of error add
`process.exit(1)` this is a not a zero exit code and PM2 will restart your server.

Again I didn't tried this, but I think it might work after some tweaking.

If this doesn't work, you always have `Restart at cron time` strategy. You can use it to restart your server every hour. You can find config in the link provided above.